# Drupal Commerce: Can't get variation type machine name from product variation object

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules

I successfully receive product variation object by its id

```
$variation = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('commerce_product_variation')->load(8);
```

Then I successfully receive its structure like

```
(
    [variation_id] => Array
        (
            [x-default] => 8
    )

    [type] => Array
        (
            [x-default] => router
        )

    [uuid] => Array
        (
            [x-default] => a44c2c31-2131-4c99-82a6-856b566d97cf
        )
    ...
```

by `print_r()` like

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($variation);
echo '</pre>';
```

Now if I try to get SKU through `$variation->sku->value`, I get it

But if I try to get variation type machine name through `$variation->type->value` I get nothing (and `gettype($variation->type->value)` returns NULL).

Still, we see it in the structure with the value `router`

Why and how to get the machine name ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's strange: the `print_r()` shows the way is `$variation->type->value`

But I've just successfully got it by

```
$variation->type[0]->target_id
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer may be useful for someone who stumbles upon this post in the future

To get the machine name of the variation type from a product variation object in Drupal 9 Commerce, you can use the following code:

```
<?php
use Drupal\commerce\PurchasableEntityInterface;

// Load the product variation object.
$product_variation = ...;

// Ensure the object is a valid product variation.
if ($product_variation instanceof PurchasableEntityInterface) {
  // Get the variation type.
  $variation_type = $product_variation->getPurchasedEntity()->bundle();
  
  // Get the variation type machine name.
  $variation_type_machine_name = $variation_type->id();
  
  // Use the variation type machine name as needed.
  ...
}
```

This code uses the **PurchasableEntityInterface** to ensure that the loaded object is a valid product variation. The **getPurchasedEntity()** method is used to get the underlying entity that represents the variation, and the **bundle()** method is used to get the variation type. The variation type machine name can then be obtained using the **`id()`** method.